# TCL - read a file, extra line

Tags: tcl

I have written the script below, and for some reason it output an extra 3rd line (top out.txt & name ). How do I stop it from outputing the last 2 line to the output file.

I think is because of this line but not too sure: set lines [split [read $list] "\n"]

```
Input put file - a.txt
**********************
abc
bcd
```

```
Output
*******
top out.txt 
name abc 
top out.txt 
name bcd 
top out.txt 
name
```

```
set outfile      [open "out.txt" w]
set list         [open "a.list" r]
set dir         "[glob a.txt]"

    foreach ddd $dir {
        set lines [split [read $list] "\n"]
        foreach line $lines {
                puts $outfile "top $dir"
                puts $outfile "name $line"
        }
    }
close $list
close $outfile
```

Comment: Try `read -nonewline $list` -- check the [read man page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/read.htm)

Comment: Or use `gets` in a loop instead of reading the entire file in one go.

Comment: Also, how do you get `out.txt` from `glob abc.txt`? Why are you even using glob here anyways? It'll only return at most one file with that pattern since there aren't any wildcards... And if that outer `foreach` does manage to run more than once, you'll only reading `a.list` the first time because it'll be at the end of the file the subsequent times....

Answer (score 1):

The core of the issue is that **`split` works with *field separators* and not *field terminators;*** this is where you see the difference between the two.

If we look at the characters of your file, we'll see this:
`a` `b` `c` `\n` `b` `c` `d` `\n`. (Technically, the `\n` might instead be `\r` `\n` or `\r`; Tcl auto-adapts to that by default for text files.)
If we `split` those characters at the `\n`, we get these substrings: `abc`, `bcd`, *and the empty string* for the characters after that final `\n`. This means that when we `join` the strings with `\n` (as the joiner string) *between* all the elements, we get the original string back again.

---

You've got a few options for dealing with this. My favourite is to add code to ignore blank lines; versions of this are particularly useful for all sorts of human-written lists (as it's fairly easy to also add in comment skipping):

```
    set lines [split [read $list] "\n"]
    foreach line $lines {
        if {$line eq ""} continue
        puts $outfile "top $dir"
        puts $outfile "name $line"
    }
```

Another option is to use the `-nonewline` option to `read` to discard that final `\n`:

```
    set lines [split [read -nonewline $list] "\n"]
    foreach line $lines {
        puts $outfile "top $dir"
        puts $outfile "name $line"
    }
```

You could also `string trimright` before splitting, but that would strip multiple newlines from the end (if they're present).

```
    set lines [split [string trimright [read $list] "\n"] "\n"]
    foreach line $lines {
        puts $outfile "top $dir"
        puts $outfile "name $line"
    }
```

Finally, if you're using a machine-generated list, you could consider just getting that code to not put a newline at the end. Sometimes that's the easiest option of all.